# custom component binding in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am trying to load custom components using knockoutjs.

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="mainDiv"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#mainDiv").append("<my-component-name></my-component-name>");
```

This appends `<my-component-name></my-component-name>` after div but does not bind my component to html.

If I use `ko.applyBindings();`  it throws error `"Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."`

I am not able to find whats wrong with bindings.

Comment: You seemed to have made your HTML invisible, buddy.

Comment: You are not supposed to create HTML with jQuery in a Knockout application. Use Knockout templating (e.g. `data-bind="foreach: xyz"` and its cousins) to create dynamic HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here I got the solution:

```
var myComp = document.createElement("my-component-name");
$("#mainDiv").append(myComp);
ko.applyBindings({},myComp);
```

Ko.applyBinding was needed to bind my component in html.

Answer (score 0):

The view is updated, but the bindings are not. You need to do `ko.applyBindings` on any elements inserted in the HTML after the bindings are applied the first time. It's a lousy solution to apply components after applying bindings. And DON'T mix knockout with jQuery or js DOM manipulation, PLEEEASSE!